# AJAX Slider Control... need second label to reflect percentage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, slider, ajaxcontroltoolkit

How would you do this? I'm not a javascript wiz, so I haven't found a solution...

I have a slider that I'd like to indicate percentage of a project budget that would be used for Project Managemant vs. Design. So in the default position, it would be a 50/50 split between project management and design. If they slid it one way, it would skew the percentage to design, and the other way, to PM... you get the idea.

So, the regular label shows a range from 0-100. I could use that for the percentage of the budget that is Project Management, say.

Now, what I want is a second label to reflect the Design percentage. (Which would be the PM label value subtracted from 100.) How would you do that?

Here's what I have so far:

```
Campaign Budget:
<br />
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Total Dollars:
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
            Use the slider to modify the percentage between Project Management and Design.
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="totaldollarsbid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            WANT DESIGN PERCENTAGE LABEL HERE
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="SliderBox" runat="server" Text="50" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender ID="SliderExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="SliderBox"
                Minimum="0" Maximum="100" BoundControlID="SliderLabel" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="SliderLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this label where you need to have design value: `<asp:Label runat="server" ID="DesignValueLabel" Text="50" />` and add script below on a page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        var extender = $find("<%= SliderExtender.ClientID %>");
        extender.remove_valueChanged(updateDesignValue);
        extender.add_valueChanged(updateDesignValue);
    }

    function updateDesignValue(sender, eventArgs) {
        var design = 100 - sender.get_Value();
        $get("<%= DesignValueLabel.ClientID %>").innerHTML = design;
    }
</script>
```

If slider doesn't placed in update panel, then instead of `pageLoad` function you can use script below (must be placed after ScriptManager or ToolkitScriptManager control)

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function () { $find("<%= SliderExtender.ClientID %>").add_valueChanged(updateDesignValue); });
```

Comment: OK, tried the script, and I get a "object null" error on this line:  extender.remove_valueChanged(updateDesignValue);  Is there something else I need to add to my site? I have the jquery stuff in the scripts folder... And then, when you say "if slider doesn't placed in update panel" you mean if it's not in an update panel (it isn't), then add "sys.application" line after the scriptmanager reference on the aspx page?

Comment: I created a totally blank page with an update panel, and put in your code. Still getting the error: "microsoft jscript runtime error: unable to get value of the property 'updateDesignValue'; object is null or undefined." So, am I missing something that allows me to run jquery stuff? (I don't think I've ever NOT gotten that error with jquery functions!)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I tried this... I added a button to "update design value"... so when the button is clicked, a jquery function updates the design label to 100 minus the PM label...

```
<asp:TextBox ID="SliderBox" runat="server" Text="50"></asp:TextBox>

<ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender ID="SliderExtender" runat="server"
TargetControlID="SliderBox"
Minimum="0"
Maximum="100" Steps="21"
BoundControlID="SliderPMLabel" 

/>
<asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Update Design Value" />
<br /> <asp:Label ID="SliderPMLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>% Project Management
<br /><asp:Label ID="SliderDesLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>% Design

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {


    $('#<%= btnTest.ClientID %>').click(function () {
    var labelText = $('#<%= SliderPMLabel.ClientID %>').html();
        $('#<%=SliderDesLabel.ClientID%>').html(100 - labelText);
        return false;
    });


}); 


</script>
```

And it works fine. BUT I want the design label value to change dynamically as the slider moves.

The one point is that it doesn't happen when the page loads... when the user selects a client from a dropdown, then this selection appears.